# How to Customize Custom Field Formula in VBA?

Tags: vba, ms-project

I'm trying to modify a formula in a custom field in VBA. I currently have the following code:

```
CustomFieldSetFormula FieldID:=pjCustomTaskNumber9
Formula = IIf(IIf([% Complete] = 100, 2, IIf([% Complete] < 100 And [Finish] > [Baseline Finish], 1, IIf([Unique ID] > maxUID, 3))))
CustomFieldProperties FieldID:=pjCustomTaskNumber9, Attribute:=pjFieldAttributeFormula, SummaryCalc:=pjCalcFormula, GraphicalIndicators:=True, AutomaticallyRolldownToAssn:=False
```

The `maxUID` will change most likely each time I plan to use the macro. When attempting to execute the code, I get the error message:

> External name not defined" for the "[% Complete]

Updated Code: Getting error on 2nd line of code still.

```
customFormula = "IIf(IIf([% Complete] = 100, 2, IIf([% Complete] < 100 And [Finish] > [Baseline Finish], 1, IIf([Unique ID] > " & maxUID & ", 3))))"
CustomFieldSetFormula FieldID:=pjCustomTaskNumber9, Formula:=customFormula
CustomFieldProperties FieldID:=pjCustomTaskNumber9, Attribute:=pjFieldAttributeFormula, SummaryCalc:=pjCalcFormula, GraphicalIndicators:=True
```

Answer (score 3):

Build the custom formula as a string and include it when calling the `CustomFieldSetFormula` method:

```
Dim customFormula As String
customFormula = "IIf([% Complete] = 100, 2, IIf([% Complete] < 100 And [Finish] > [Baseline Finish], 1, IIf([Unique ID] > " & maxUID & ", 3)))"
CustomFieldSetFormula FieldID:=pjCustomTaskNumber9, Formula:=customFormula
CustomFieldProperties FieldID:=pjCustomTaskNumber9, Attribute:=pjFieldAttributeFormula, SummaryCalc:=pjCalcFormula, GraphicalIndicators:=True, AutomaticallyRolldownToAssn:=False
```

Comment: Thank you for the comment! I used the code as you provided and am getting an error on the 3rd line (CustomFieldSetFormula), being highlighted in yellow.

Comment: Try removing the AutomaticallyRolldownToAssn part.

Comment: Still didn't work for me unfortunately. Please take a look at my updated code, I edited the initial question so I can show you what I have now maybe I made a basic mistake somewhere.

Comment: The formula had an extraneous leading IIf. Remove that and one of the trailing closing parentheses and it should work now.