# Find the tasks, where there is a certain date between start and finish

Tags: vba, ms-project

I am trying to create a filter to find all tasks that are running on a certain day.

```
Task 1  10 März 2021 08:00  23 April 2021 08:00
Task 2  23 April 2021 08:00 26 Mai 2021 08:00
Task 3  20 Mai 2021 08:00   26 Mai 2021 08:00
```

Search for 22. Mai 2021, should return Task 1 and Task 2 in the Gantt Chart.

I have 4k+ rows, and I would like to see only these tasks.

Could be filter, function or VBA.

I am not getting it with the filters.

I am familiar with Excel VBA, but new to MS Project.

Answer (score 1):

The trick to finding tasks that are running within a certain window of time is look for tasks that *start before the end of the window* **AND** *finish after the start of the window*.

To find tasks that are running on 22 Mai 2021 (e.g. the window is one day), use this: `Start < #22/5/2021# And Finish >= #21/5/2021#`.

This will find all four cases you want:

1. Tasks that start before the window starts but finish during the window.
2. Tasks that start during the window and finish after the window ends.
3. Tasks that start and finish during the window.
4. Tasks that start before the window starts and finish after the window ends.

In this case you are looking for a window that is a single day, however this method works well for longer periods--for example, to find all tasks running in the next 90 days.

Also see [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55156271/identifying-specific-resources-that-are-overallocated-in-ms-project-using-timesc/55169657#55169657) with graphic illustrating 1-4.

Comment: Sorry for the late answer: this is partly the way I tried in the meantime: User defined field with formula `IIf(([Start]<=DateValue("21/5/202")) And ([End]>=DateValue("21/5/202"));"YES";"NO")` and then filter for "YES". Looking into vba now and your link.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I found 3 ways of solving this:

1. VBA and custom field with formula (fastest):
   Thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/a/48754562/3157070

```
Sub DateFilter()

Dim dateString As String
Dim customFormula As String

dateString = VBA.Interaction.InputBox("Date Input", "Date", "01/01/2020")


customFormula = "IIf(([Start]<=DateValue(""" & dateString & """)) And ([End]>=DateValue(""" & dateString & """));""YES"";""NO"")"
'Debug.Print customFormula

'put it into custom field Text24
CustomFieldSetFormula FieldID:=pjCustomTaskText24, Formula:=customFormula
CustomFieldProperties FieldID:=pjCustomTaskText24, Attribute:=pjFieldAttributeFormula, SummaryCalc:=pjCalcNone, GraphicalIndicators:=False

'Call custom filter
FilterApply "YES"
End Sub
```

2. Custom field with formula without vba:

```
IIf(([Start]<=DateValue("7/14/2022")) And ([End]>=DateValue("7/14/2022"));"YES";"NO")
```

3. VBA only (I don't know why, but takes several minutes for 4000 rows...):

Thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/a/59340705/3157070

```
Sub DateFilter1()

Dim T As Task
Dim dateString As String

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

dateString = VBA.Interaction.InputBox("Date Input", "Date", "01/01/2020")

For Each T In ActiveProject.Tasks

    If T.ScheduledStart <= dateString And T.ScheduledFinish >= dateString Then

        T.Text24 = "YES"

    Else
        T.Text24 = "NO"

    End If
Next

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
FilterApply "YES"

End Sub
```

All of these solved my problem.
Please share your improvements.

Answer (score 0):

I watched a youtube and "mad schedules" add the line below to leave out the empty lines:

```
If Not (tsk Is Nothing) Then
  ...your IF-code...
End if
```